# How to open a JavaFX Window only once time

Tags: java, javafx, window, fxml, stage

I have a JavaFX application and I need simple to avoid user from opening the same window inside the application more than once.

I tried to find some solution, but nothing get applicable.

As a sample... I have a window that give me payments options, its not a modal, it's a new stage. While I click the button to open that window, it's open, doesn't matter if there is another instance of this same stage running, simple open new windows every click. I want to avoid this. Like switch to the already opened stage window when click the button, or simply miss the click if that window is already opened.

Comment: keep track of that it's opened once (and disable the button until closed again)

Answer (score 5):

You just need to keep track of the stage and only open a new one if its not already shown.  You could also choose to disable the `Button` if the new window is showing, but I prefer to have the new window simply brought back in front so the user knows it's there.

You can do this by creating a reference to your `Stage` and then checking if it is `null` or showing within the button's event handler.

Here is an MCVE to demonstrate:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    /**
     * Reference to the new Window that will allow only one instance at a time.
     */
    private Stage newWindowStage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Button openWindow = new Button("Open Window");

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Set the button to open the new Window Stage
        // **********************************************************************************************
        openWindow.setOnAction(event -> {

            // **********************************************************************************************
            // Check if the Stage is already showing.
            // **********************************************************************************************
            if (newWindowStage == null || !newWindowStage.isShowing()) {

                // **********************************************************************************************
                // The new window is not currently open, so create/show it
                // **********************************************************************************************
                newWindowStage = new Stage();
                newWindowStage.setWidth(300);
                newWindowStage.setHeight(300);
                newWindowStage.setScene(new Scene(
                        new VBox(
                                new Label("New Window!")
                        )
                ));
                newWindowStage.show();
            } else {
                // **********************************************************************************************
                // The window is already open, so bring it to the front of focus
                // **********************************************************************************************
                newWindowStage.toFront();
            }

        });

        root.getChildren().add(openWindow);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setWidth(200);
        primaryStage.setHeight(200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Application");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tryed that solution, but when I run it, I get... nothing when button pressed.

Comment: Did you copy all of the code I posted? What version JDK are you using?